# ¿Cómo mostrar más opciones al posicionarse en una opción de SELECT BOX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente SELECT BOX y me gustaría mostrar otro listado de opciones al posicionarse en una de ellas. No se si utiliza JS o en el mismo HTML.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   <select name='lugar_nacimiento' id='lugar_nacimiento' class='form-control' required>
    <option value='Aguascalientes'>Aguascalientes</option>
    <option value='Chihuahua'>Chihuahua</option>
    <option value='CDMX'>Ciudad de México</option> <----Mostrar el listado de delegaciones  si se posiciona en esta opción.    
   </select>
```

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer se hace con li, ul , busca en google menu lateral desplegable html hay miles de páginas que lo explican :)

Comment: No me queda claro lo que necesitas... alimentar otro `select` según la opción seleccionada o hacer un submenú como comenta @EduBw ?. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar una imagen de ejemplo con el resultado que quieres obtener.

Comment: A partir de lo propuesto, para mí la opción más factible sería usar un segundo elemento `<select>` para mostrar otro nivel de opciones de acuerdo a lo seleccionado en el primer elemento. Pero es solo una propuesta. Sería mucho más conveniente que complementes la pregunta, idealmente con una muestra gráfica de lo que se quiere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que te entendí, te pongo un ejemplo práctico utilizando jquery.

## Referencias jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Código javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ciudades").change(function() {          
                $("#delegaciones > option").remove();
                cargar_delegaciones($("#ciudades option:selected").val());
            });
        });

        function cargar_delegaciones(delegaciones)
        {
            var array = [];

            if(delegaciones == "Aguascalientes"){
                array = ["delegacion_1","delegacion_2","delegacion_3"];
            } 
            else if (delegaciones == "Chihuahua"){
                array = ["delegacion_4","delegacion_5","delegacion_6"];
            } 
            else if (delegaciones == "CDMX"){
                array = ["delegacion_7","delegacion_8","delegacion_9"];
            } 

            for(var i in array)
            { 
                document.getElementById("delegaciones").innerHTML += "<option value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>";
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Nota: he simulado la carga de datos desde js, puedes cargar las optiones del select desde una respuesta del servidor por ajax y pintarlo en html.

## Código html

```
<body>
        <form class="insp_p" action=" " method="post">
            <fieldset id="fie_ciudades"> 
                <br>
                    <label>Ciudades</label
                    <br>    
                    <select width="100px" id="ciudades" name="intervalo1" class="selectp">
                        <option value="Seleccione" disabled >Seleccione una ciudad</option>
                        <option value="Aguascalientes">Aguascalientes</option>
                        <option value="Chihuahua">Chihuahua</option>
                        <option value="CDMX">Ciudad de México</option>
                    </select>
                <br>    
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="fie_delegaciones"> 
                <br>
                    <label>Delegaciones</label
                    <br>    
                    <select width="100px" id="delegaciones">
                        <!--<option value=0>Ciudad 1</option>
                        <option value=1>Ciudad 2</option>
                        <option value=2>Ciudad 3</option>
                        <option value=3>Ciudad 4</option>-->
                    </select>
                <br>    
            </fieldse>

        </form>
    </body>
```